# How to delete an object in sfml

Tags: visual-c++, sfml

my Rockclass

```
void rock::create(sf::Vector2f pos)
{
    tex.loadFromFile("Images/meteorBig.png");
    spr.setTexture(tex);
    spr.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(pos.x, pos.y));
    std::cout << pos.x << std::endl;
}

void rock::remove()
{

}

void rock::draw(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    spr.move(0.0f, +.05f);
    window.draw(spr);
}
```

my main class

```
rock* rob = new rock();

rob->create(sf::Vector2f(300.0f + rand() % 50 + 10, 0.0f));
```

and in renderer i have

```
rob->draw(mywindow);
```

and in collision checking i have

```
if (bo.sprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects(rob->spr.getGlobalBounds()))
    {
        cout << "Collides" << endl;
        delete rob;
    }
```

when ever the my bullet hit the rock,it debugs collides perfectly but when i use `delete rob;` inorder to delete the object it crashes

with this message

> Unhandled exception at 0x55111BBE (sfml-graphics-d-2.dll) in
>   SpaceDroid.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0xFEEEFEF2.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you delete rob, your pointer, and then attempt to access the void pointer again in the same check the next time. Hence the access violation.

As regards to a solution, you could check if rob equals nullptr (assuming c++11) or, even better would be to reconsider your use of raw pointers all together.

I don't know the context of your program, if rock is something that gets made and deleted frequent, consider holding ONE rock texture object in a persistent 'texture manager' and then creating and removing your rock sprites/objects in a container. Perhaps have a 'rockList' or 'entityList' that is looped through each frame. Then removal becomes a trivial '.erase'

Comment: I think your main point is correct but there are two things that are inexact in your answer. First, the "void" pointer is not the correct term. You probably meant *to access a **dangling** pointer*. Second, it's probably just a question of phrasing but checking for equality with `nullptr` (or `0` in C++98) you actually need to set your pointer to `nullptr` at some point, typically you do `delete ptr; ptr = nullptr;`.